# Copying OpenCL Buffers not working

Tags: c, opencl

I am trying to learn OpenCL. I got an environment correctly setup (tested with some example programs).

Now I am trying to program an example kernel where it simply squares the number that is passed to it. However, I get random data in the return buffer and never the correct answer. Here is my code:

https://gist.github.com/kylecook80/1582719480e4f40d2939

Comment: N.B. the link the OP provides might look like a code dump, but it's actually a (near-)minimal and well-written example (good).

Comment: @imallett thank you! I will fix the checking of error codes then it will be complete :)

Comment: @imallet If you are interested: https://github.com/kylecook80/opencl-square

Comment: Thanks; I've already got my own CL code which is . . . considerably more general. But, I already +1-ed this question since your example was about as much an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) as is possible in OpenCL. It's unfortunate that this extreme simplicity (and the lack of error checking implied thereby) also happened to be your program's fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always check the return status of each OpenCL call to see if it was successful or not.

If you do that, you will notice an error at line 47:

```
cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "hello", NULL);
```

You have no OpenCL kernel named `"hello"`, it should be `"square"`.

Comment: Ah of course, I knew that would come back to bite me. Thanks for pointing out the error, I will stop being lazy...